# Type signature for a TypeScript HOF

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following JavaScript function adds a before and after advice for a given function. I am trying to add TypeScript type signature for this function.

```
function wrap(fn, before, after) {
    var id = function(x) { return x };
    before = before || id;
    after = after || id;

    return function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var modifiedArgs;

        try {
            modifiedArgs = before.apply(this, args);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

        var result = undefined;
        try {
            result = fn.apply(this, modifiedArgs || args);
        } finally {
            try {
                after.apply(this, args);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The types I could come up with are:

- `fn` is of type `Function`
- `after` is of type `(_:any[]) => any[]`
- return type is `Function`

What should the type of `before` be? It takes an `any[]` and returns either `void` or `any[]`. Also, is it possible to encode the fact that the return type has the same type signature as `fn`?

Comment: I think changing the semantics of `before` advice to return either `null` or modified arguments array is the way to go here. I haven't tried it yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before could be `(_:any[]) => any[]`

If you want to encode the return type in your function signature just do something like this:

```
function wrap(fn, before, after) : Function {  ...function... }
```

Comment: `(_:any[]) => any[]?` won't compile. I want the return type to be a function of the same type as `fn` i.e. if `fn` is `(_:string)=>string`, then the return type is `(_:string)=>string`; if `fn` is `(_:string, _:number)=>string` then return type is `(_:string, _:number)=>string` etc. I admit that this needs a quite expressive type system, so it is likely that it is not possible in TS, but I was curious.

Comment: my apologies on the noncompile! are you just not returning in that case for the function or are you returning null? i would recommend you return null as then you can have the message sig be: (_:any[]) : any[] and have that be valid

Comment: as for fn, that is beyond me. i dont believe it is possible in TS currently.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing this as:

```
module Foo {
    export interface Wrappable extends Function {
        (...rest) : any;
    }

    export function wrap<U extends Wrappable>(fn: U, 
                                              before: (...args) => any[], 
                                              after: (...args) => void): U {
        var id = function(x) { return x };
        before = before || id;
        after = after || id;

        return <U> function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var modifiedArgs;

            try {
                modifiedArgs = before.apply(this, args);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

            var result = undefined;
            try {
                result = fn.apply(this, modifiedArgs || args);
            } finally {
                try {
                    after.apply(this, args);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}

var orig = function(s: string): void {
    console.log("Hello!");
};

var before = function (s: string): any[] {
    console.log("before calling orig(" + s + ")");
    return [s];
};

var after = function (s: string): void {
    console.log("after calling orig(" + s + ")");
};

var f = Foo.wrap(orig, before, after);
f("1");
// f(); // ERROR
// f(1); // ERROR
// f("1", "1"); // ERROR
```

Notice that the return value of `Foo.wrap` is the a function of the same type as the first argument, which was impressive feat by the TS type inference!